# Get input from drop down into Python inside Django app

Tags: python, django

I've been stuck on this issue for a few weeks as I'm not very familiar with how to get the ajax set up. I'm working on a Django app which is basically one page that has a Dropdown menu. I would like to get whatever the user selects from the Dropdown menu and pass that data into my views.py so I can use that information to display a graph. Right now the graph part is working (I can pass in hard coded data into it and it will generate the graph) and my dropdown is working as well. However, I don't know how to get data from the drop down into my views.py. Here is how it looks.

Display.html

```
{% extends "RecordEvent/nav.html" %}

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>


{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="padded">
        <div class="download-header">
            <h3>Logs</h3>
            <div class="row inline download-header">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                     <div class="dropdown padding col-lg-6">
                          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            <span id="dropdownTitle" class="">Measurable</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            {% include 'RecordEvent/includes/EntryDropdown.html' %}
                          </ul>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='padded'>
    <div class='col-sm-12' url-endpoint='{% url "api-data" %}'>
        <h1>Graph Data</h1>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>  
</div>

<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = 'display/api/chart/data/'
var defaultData = []
var defaultLabels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        defaultLabels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        console.log(data)
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: defaultLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# Measurable',
                    data: defaultData,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

{% endblock %}

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

The first div creates the Dropdown menu. Everything below is to get the graph setup.

views.py

```
@login_required
def DisplayView(request):
    return render(request,'DisplayData/Display.html')

class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_entries = models.Entries.objects.all().filter(parent=2) #change to input from drop down
        all_id = models.Entries.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
        all_measurables = models.Measurables.objects.all().filter(user_id=1) #change to current user


        all_times = [m.timestamp for m in all_entries]

        all_data = []
        for m in all_entries:
            data = m.data
            json_data = json.loads(data)
            value = json_data['value']
            all_data.append(value)


        data = {
            "labels": all_times,
            "default": all_data,
            #"default": all_parent,
        }   
        return Response(data)

@login_required
def LogDisplay(request):
    measurables=[entry for entry in models.Measurables.objects.all().filter(user_id=request.user.id)]

    return render(request, 'DisplayData/Logs.html',{'dropdown':measurables})
```

I need to get the value from the drop down into the where the comment says get value from drop down.

How can I do it?

Comment: how are u submiting the form to the api

Comment: Thats what I'm having trouble with since I don't know how to do POST. Right now its just displaying the form. @Rhea

Comment: do you want to refresh the page or post via ajax?

Comment: Whenever the user picks something from the drop down, I want to send that value to views.py.

Answer (score 0):

to post via form

```
<form method='post' action = 'api url'>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        {% include 'RecordEvent/includes/EntryDropdown.html' %}
                      </ul>
</form>
```

amd in  `views.py` access with

```
request.post[<name>]
```

to post via ajax

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: <api url>,
      type:'post',
      data:{<name>:$(this).html()},
   })
```

Comment: For request.post[<name>] do I pass in the variable name in python or the form name that's in html? And where does the ajax code go, right after the form?

Comment: ajax code goes in the `{%block jquery %}`
<name> is the same name you give in the ajax `data:{<name:>}`